# Programatically bringing a Datagrid column into view (horizontal scroll)

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

I would like to bring a column into view programatically. I have a lot of columns and when they are off screen i would like to select a cell and bring that cell into view,  i can select a cell that is off screen and when i horizontal scroll to bring the cell visible the cell is selected.

i know you can do this with the rows, i.e ScrollIntoView but how about columns?

anyone had any luck doing this? and if so how :) (of course)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer : use the datagrid method.

```
public void ScrollIntoView(object item, DataGridColumn column);
```

which takes a column. simple.

Answer (score 1):

aran, suppose you want to go to 30 th column, try setting the horizontal offset of the scroll viewer.

like,

```
columnCount = 30;
offset = columCount * Columnwidth
scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(offest);
```

best,
Quafin