# How can I scroll to the last column of a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programatically bringing a Datagrid column into view (horizontal scroll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107362/programatically-bringing-a-datagrid-column-into-view-horizontal-scroll)

I use WPF with .NET 4 and the WPF Toolkit DataGrid. 
I have a rather wide datagrid, its first column is frozen, SelectionUnit - Cell.

All I need is to scroll this datagrid to its last column after loading of the window.
I've tried to 'put' my datagrid into a ScrollViewer - but if I use it first column of the datagrid ceases to be frozen.
I've tried to use datagrid's ScrollIntoView but I haven't selected item for it and I can't select a row to get it (because of my SelectionUnit - cell)...

What can I do to solve my problem? Thanks!

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/2107362/920384

Comment: I saw this post too... But after loading of the window SelectedItem of datagrid is null. If I could programatically select last cell in first row...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for this you simply need to use the function `ScrollIntoView()` on your `DataGrid` with the first row and the last column as follows:

```
object row = this.dataGrid1.Items[0]; //Grab the first row
DataGridColumn col = this.dataGrid1.Columns[this.dataGrid1.Columns.Count - 1]; //Grab the last column
this.dataGrid1.ScrollIntoView(row, col); //Set the view
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew that there is a simply solution))